# Is it possible to filter directly connected networks redistribute with BGP based on a peer basis?

Tags: networking, cisco, bgp

Assume a simplified case in which router R1 is connected to two BGP peers: one eBGP peer and one iBGP peer. Is there a possibility to advertise directly connected routes only to one of them automatically i.e. whenever a new directly connected network to R1 appears it is advertised only to one of BGP peers while the other peer receives other routes but not those that are directly connected to R1?

Comment: You'll probably have a better target audience at the [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Will try to ask the question there.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify manually the networks you want to advertise to each peer in the router bgp configuration,

router bgp

network X.X.X.X mask X.X.X.X

You can also use the redistribute command in the router bgp configuration, to advertise all the directly connected networks, this configuration is unique by peer, so, you can configure this in the one you want to advertise your directly conected network.

router bgp

address-family ipv4 unicast

redistribute connected

If your configuration is more complex you can use a route map and a prefix list to filter the network you want to share to each peer, take a look of this official Cisco documentation.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/configuration/15-mt/irg-15-mt-book/irg-oubound-route-filtering.html

I hope this information be helpful to you. :)